# Restful api and operations like search and invite

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design, http-verbs

Restful api should not use verb in path, but how to design api for:

- search products
- filter products
- invite friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always ask yourself:

> What are my Resources?

- List products: `GET /api/products`
- Filter products: `GET /api/products?status={{status}}`
- Invite friends: `POST /api/invitation`

Note that the path (REST Resource) is a noun (`invitation`), not a verb (`invite`).